# Why can't I use cocoa frameworks in different forked processes?

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, fork, bsd

I was playing with the `NSSound` class to play a sound in a background process of my own so as to not block user input. I decided to call `fork()` but that is giving me problems. At the very moment the sound is allocated the forked process crashes. The funny thing is if I construct an example which only calls `fork()`, then the child process can call `NSSound` without problems, the crashes come only if I try to use other cocoa APIs *before* the `fork()`call. See this example with the `crashme?()` calls commented:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <math.h>

#define FILENAME \
    "/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/" \
    "Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/dock/drag to trash.aif"

void crashme1(void)
{
    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"false file"];
    NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc]
        initWithContentsOfFile:path byReference:YES];
}

void crashme2(void)
{
    NSInteger tag = 0;
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
        performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation
        source:@"." destination:nil
        files:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"false file"] tag:&tag];
}

double playAif(void)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:FILENAME];
    NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc]
        initWithContentsOfFile:path byReference:YES];
    [path release];

    if (!sound) {
        [pool release];
        return -1;
    }

    const double ret = [sound duration];
    [sound play];
    [sound autorelease];
    [pool release];
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //crashme1();
    //crashme2();
    int childpid = fork();
    if (0 == childpid)  {
        printf("Starting playback\n");
        double wait = playAif();
        sleep(ceil(wait));
        wait = playAif();
        sleep(ceil(wait));
        printf("Finished playback\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this from the commandline it works, but if I uncomment one of the calls to either `crashme?()` functions the playback in the forked process never starts. Is it because any of the Cocoa framework APIs are not [async-signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676371/can-i-call-chdir-or-setenv-after-fork-on-mac-os-x) safe? Is there any way to make the calls async signal safe by wrapping them somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll quote the Leopard CoreFoundation Framework Release Notes. I don't know if they're still online, since Apple tends to replace rather than extend the Core Foundation release notes.

> #### CoreFoundation and fork()
>
> Due to the behavior of fork(), CoreFoundation cannot be used on the
>   child-side of fork(). If you fork(), you must follow that with an
>   exec*() call of some sort, and you should not use CoreFoundation APIs
>   within the child, before the exec*(). The applies to all higher-level
>   APIs which use CoreFoundation, and since you cannot know what those
>   higher-level APIs are doing, and whether they are using CoreFoundation
>   APIs, you should not use any higher-level APIs either. This includes
>   use of the daemon() function.
>
> Additionally, per POSIX, only async-cancel-safe functions are safe to
>   use on the child side of fork(), so even use of lower-level
>   libSystem/BSD/UNIX APIs should be kept to a minimum, and ideally to
>   only async-cancel-safe functions.
>
> This has always been true, and there have been notes made of this on
>   various Cocoa developer mailling lists in the past. But CoreFoundation
>   is taking some stronger measures now to "enforce" this limitation, so
>   we thought it would be worthwhile to add a release note to call this
>   out as well. A message is written to stderr when something uses API
>   which is definitely known not to be safe in CoreFoundation after
>   fork(). If file descriptor 2 has been closed, however, you will get no
>   message or notice, which is too bad. We tried to make processes
>   terminate in a very recognizable way, and did for a while and that was
>   very handy, but backwards binary compatibility prevented us from doing
>   so.

In other words, it has never been safe to do much of anything on the child side of a `fork()` other than exec a new program.

Besides the general POSIX prohibition, an oft-mentioned explanation is: a) pretty much all Cocoa programs are multithreaded these days, what with GCD and the like. B) when you `fork()`, only the calling thread survives into the child process; the other threads just vanish. Since those threads could have been manipulating shared resources, the child process can't rely on having sane state. For example, the `malloc()` implementation may have a lock to protect shared structures and that lock could have been held by one of the now-gone threads at the time of the `fork()`. So, if the remaining thread tries to allocate memory, it may hang indefinitely. Other shared data structures may simply be in a corrupted state. Etc.