# Why is tzset() a lot slower after forking on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, fork, libc

Calling `tzset()` after forking appears to be very slow. I only see the slowness if I first call `tzset()` in the parent process before forking. My `TZ` environment variable is not set. I `dtruss`'d my test program and it revealed the child process reads `/etc/localtime` for every `tzset()` invocation, while the parent process only reads it once. This file access seems to be the source of the slowness, but I wasn't able to determine why it's accessing it every time in the child process.

Here is my test program foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void check(char *msg);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  check("before");

  pid_t c = fork();
  if (c == 0) {
    check("fork");
    exit(0);
  }

  wait(NULL);

  check("after");
}

void check(char *msg) {
  struct timeval tv;

  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  time_t start = tv.tv_sec;
  suseconds_t mstart = tv.tv_usec;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    tzset();
  }

  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  double delta = (double)(tv.tv_sec - start);
  delta += (double)(tv.tv_usec - mstart)/1000000.0;

  printf("%s took: %fs\n", msg, delta);
}
```

I compiled and executed foo.c like this:

```
[muir@muir-work-mb scratch]$ clang -o foo foo.c
[muir@muir-work-mb scratch]$ env -i ./foo
before took: 0.002135s
fork took: 1.122254s
after took: 0.001120s
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.1 (also reproduced on 10.9.5).

I originally noticed the slowness via ruby (Time#localtime slow in child process).

Comment: Minor: recommend `difftime(tv.tv_sec, start)` rather than `(double)(tv.tv_sec - start)`.  `(double)` in `delta += (double)...` is not needed.

Comment: I think the primary reason for the poor performance is that it's actually checking that the timezone file hasn't changed **every** localtime call - it's doing the mac thing of behaving like the system setting can change from under it. The poor fork behaviour may be a side effect of the file change notification mechanism that's being used not functioning properly across a `fork()` - this is only a supposition based on running the code through instruments and some googling.

Comment: I liked the notification theory so I investigated bit more and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Ken Thomases's response may be correct, but I was curious about a more specific answer because I still find the slowness unexpected behavior for a single-threaded program performing such a simple/common operation after `fork`ing. After examining http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.1.1/stdtime/FreeBSD/localtime.c (not 100% sure this is the correct source), I think I have an answer.

The code uses passive notifications to determine if the time zone has changed (as opposed to `stat`ing `/etc/localtime` every time). It appears that the registered notification token becomes invalid in the child process after `fork`ing. Furthermore, the code treats the error from using an invalid token as a positive notification that the timezone has changed, and proceeds to read `/etc/localtime` every time. I guess this is the kind of undefined behavior you can get after `fork`ing? It would be nice if the library noticed the error and re-registered for the notification, though.

Here is the snippet of code from localtime.c that mixes the error value with the status value:

```
nstat = notify_check(p->token, &ncheck);
if (nstat || ncheck) {
```

I demonstrated that the registration token becomes invalid after fork using this program:

```
#include <notify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bail(char *msg) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", msg);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int token, something_changed, ret;

  notify_register_check("com.apple.system.timezone", &token);

  ret = notify_check(token, &something_changed);
  if (ret)
    bail("notify_check #1 failed");
  if (!something_changed)
    bail("expected change on first call");

  ret = notify_check(token, &something_changed);
  if (ret)
    bail("notify_check #2 failed");
  if (something_changed)
    bail("expected no change");

  pid_t c = fork();
  if (c == 0) {
    ret = notify_check(token, &something_changed);
    if (ret) {
      if (ret == NOTIFY_STATUS_INVALID_TOKEN)
        printf("ret is invalid token\n");

      if (!notify_is_valid_token(token))
        printf("token is not valid\n");

      bail("notify_check in fork failed");
    }

    if (something_changed)
      bail("expected not changed");

    exit(0);
  }

  wait(NULL);
}
```

And ran it like this:

```
muir-mb:projects muir$ clang -o notify_test notify_test.c 
muir-mb:projects muir$ ./notify_test 
ret is invalid token
token is not valid
Error: notify_check in fork failed
```

Answer (score 3):

You're lucky you didn't experience [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)!

POSIX states that only async-signal-safe functions are legal to call in the child process after the `fork()` and before a call to an `exec*()` function. From the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) (emphasis added):

> … the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the `exec` functions is called.
>
> …
>
> There are two reasons why POSIX programmers call `fork()`. One reason is
>   to create a new thread of control within the same program (which was
>   originally only possible in POSIX by creating a new process); the
>   other is to create a new process running a different program. In the
>   latter case, the call to `fork()` is soon followed by a call to one of
>   the `exec` functions.
>
> The general problem with making `fork()` work in a multi-threaded world
>   is what to do with all of the threads. There are two alternatives. One
>   is to copy all of the threads into the new process. This causes the
>   programmer or implementation to deal with threads that are suspended
>   on system calls or that might be about to execute system calls that
>   should not be executed in the new process. The other alternative is to
>   copy only the thread that calls `fork()`. This creates the difficulty
>   that the state of process-local resources is usually held in process
>   memory. If a thread that is not calling `fork()` holds a resource, that
>   resource is never released in the child process because the thread
>   whose job it is to release the resource does not exist in the child
>   process.
>
> When a programmer is writing a multi-threaded program, the first
>   described use of `fork()`, creating new threads in the same program, is
>   provided by the `pthread_create()` function. The `fork()` function is thus
>   used only to run new programs, and **the effects of calling functions
>   that require certain resources between the call to `fork()` and the call
>   to an `exec` function are undefined**.

There are lists of async-signal-safe functions [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html). For any other function, if it's not specifically documented that the implementations on the platforms to which you're deploying add a non-standard safety guarantee, then you must consider it unsafe and its behavior on the child side of a `fork()` to be undefined.

Comment: "... the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called" seems to be referring to what happens when "multi-threaded process calls fork()". So I don't think it applies to the above question.

Comment: That's the rationale, but I don't believe the rule is conditional. Because any program may become multi-threaded, the system libraries need to account for that. They may register `pthread_atfork()` callbacks whose implementation assumes the program could be multi-threaded at the time of the fork. They may therefore temporarily put shared state into a "fork-safe" state in the prepare callback, restore them in the parent callback, but leave them like that in the child callback (because it's not required to restore them there).

Comment: I think this is an overly broad reading. Neither APUE, The Linux Programming Environment, nor Butenhof mention anything about this restriction outside of a multithreaded program, which would be a pretty glaring omission if it were true. The standard clearly isolates this to "If a multi-threaded process calls fork()" as @psanford points out - I think a thread-ready system library that didn't leave the child fork-safe in a single-threaded process in the way you describe would just be broken, since there's really no scope for a problem in such a case unless one is created.

Comment: From OS X's [`pthread_atfork()` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_atfork.3.html): "only async-signal-safe functions are allowed on the child side of fork()". Similarly, see [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991036/why-cant-i-use-cocoa-frameworks-in-different-forked-processes). I got my interpretation of the standard from Apple. Also, the standard clearly says that the only remaining valid use of `fork()` is to run new programs.

Comment: Re your last sentence, it only says that immediately after "When a programmer is writing a multi-threaded program, the first described use of `fork()`, creating new threads in the same program, is provided by the `pthread_create()` function", restricting that comment to multi-threaded programs. If you're using third party frameworks like Cocoa, then obviously it's fair game there, but no sane ISO or base UNIX library should randomly create threads other than completely transparently, or you could *never* use a function like `malloc()`, since POSIX doesn't require it to be thread-safe.

Comment: That paragraph is saying that `fork()` is not the way to achieve (primitive) multi-threading, as described two paragraphs prior. Now there's `pthread_create()` for that. But that sentence does not suggest that the subsequent one only applies in multi-threaded programs. It's saying there's only one use left for `fork()` given that the other use is obviated: for running new programs. That's as true for single-threaded programs as it is for multi-threaded ones. The OP is doing what the standard describes as the old way of doing multi-threading. What do you think it's talking about if not that?

Comment: Simply that "when [you are] writing a multi-threaded program", then you use `pthread_create()` to "create a new thread of control", not `fork()`, since that's presumably why you chose to write such a program. For other cases, it earlier says "there are two reasons why POSIX programmers call `fork()`", not "there *were* two reasons...but now they always use pthreads for one of them". Effectively deprecating the use of `fork()` for this purpose would be a very substantial change that hopefully would be highlighted very clearly, not relegated to an ambiguous discussion in a rationale section.